# Search in sql table by Name

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to search for the records with a name containing certain search characters but I keep getting an error in MySQL

`syntax near %off% AND offers.isExpired=0 GROUP BY products_offers.offer_id`

Here's the MySQL query

```
SELECT 
    offers.* , 
    products_offers.product_id, 
    group_concat(zones_offers.zone_id) as zones 
FROM products_offers 
join offers on products_offers.offer_id = offers.id 
join zones_offers on offers.id = zones_offers.offer_id 
WHERE 
    offers.type = ${type} 
    AND offers.name like %${searchItem}% 
    AND offers.isExpired = 0 
GROUP BY products_offers.offer_id 
limit ${skip},${limit}
```

Comment: hint: you're missing 2  `'`s

Comment: What if you write it as `offers.name like '%${searchItem}%'`? Although, you'll need to explain what language you're context is since it may impact how the quotes are treated (*e.g.*, is this being done within Javascript?).

Comment: i tried adding the 's but the same error is happening,

Comment: am using mysql with nodejs

Comment: this is my full function

connection.query(
      `SELECT offers.* , products_offers.product_id, group_concat(zones_offers.zone_id) as zones FROM products_offers join offers on products_offers.offer_id = offers.id join zones_offers on offers.id = zones_offers.offer_id WHERE offers.type = ${type} AND offers.name like '%${searchItem}%' AND offers.isExpired=0 GROUP BY products_offers.offer_id limit 
        ${skip},${limit}`,
      function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) {
          //handle error
        } else {   //handle result}

Comment: note that the query is surrounded by back ticks `

Comment: So is your error message now reading, `syntax near '%off%' AND offers.isExpired=0...` (note the single quotes)?

Comment: @lurker i dont get what you mean

Comment: You said you put the single quotes in and get the same error. What exactly is the new error message? It can't be identical to the old one since the old doesn't show your single quotes.